# How to use different temporary strings in a C loop?

Tags: c, c-strings, pebble-watch

I'm developing under a small C API and I need to create an array of structs, each with different titles. From my background in PHP I wrote the following code excerpt:

```c
char *title = "";
for(int w = 0; w < total_workouts; w++) {
    snprintf(title, 10, "Workout %c", workouts[w].letter);
    workout_menu[w] = (SimpleMenuItem) { .title = title };
}
```

However, the `title` variable is sent as a pointer to the `SimpleMenuItem` object, and thus all the menu entries get the same title. I spent some time fiddling with arrays of strings and etc and could't make it work.

How would I fix the snippet of code to have different string pointers for each menu entry (each passage inside the `for`)?

Comment: Code needs space for `title`? `snprintf()` needs a size?

Comment: sorry, cleaning up the code i removed accidentally the length sent to snprintf. It's fixed, but that's not the original source of problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create some space for title dynamically INSIDE The loop

```
workout_menu[w].title = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
```

And then use sprintf/snprintf to copy directly into the title member of SimpleMenuItem (not a local variable)

```
sprintf(workout_menu[w].title, "Workout %c", workouts[w].letter)
```

Remember to use free() when you're finished so you don't have a memory leak.

Comment: Side note, I didn't validate how you are calling snprintf etc etc. This is just a modification assuming the rest of your code is valid.

Comment: that looks great, but then I got this...
`error: passing argument 1 of 'snprintf' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type`

Comment: This is because youre using snprintf wrong, like I said I didnt validate it :) http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf  notice the arguments do not match yours -- I updated it to use sprintf, because you dont need the "n" variant

Comment: `snprintf(workout_menu[w].title, sizeof workout_menu[w].title, "Workout %c", workouts[w].letter)`?

Comment: chux - sprintf dosn't take a size. int sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...);

Comment: as i said in the question comments, that was a editing mistake, not happening in the original code. this has nothing to do with snprintf args and etc. I'm using it correctly, as I edited later the question: `snprintf(workout_menu[w].title, 10, "Workout %c", letter)`

Comment: Furthermore, I'm using snprintf because it's included in the API I'm using, and thus I don't need to include any other header to format strings.

Comment: Is your definition for the title member "const char title[255]" or "char title[255]"?

Comment: I don't have the definition, that struct come from the API :(

Comment: Found somewhere the header file, and yes, it's `const char *title`

Comment: Oh. In that case you to use dynamic allocation to create a new string and set that pointer value there. Will update answer.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to avoid dynamic allocation as I'm very new to C and memory management, and the device (a Pebble) is very, very short on RAM, and thus I'm afraid of leaks... haha
Wouldn't it be possible to be done using an array of strings instead, given I know the array size (`total_workouts`) and the strings size itself (10, as it's always "Workout X")?

Comment: You could theoretically create a char[total_workouts][10] if total_workouts is a constant and not changing in code, and then print to char[w], but I don't recommend this. Besides the restriction on total_workouts being constant you then have to worry about it being used out of scope. This looks designed to make you use dynamic allocation :)

Comment: ok, you got me, total_workouts is not constant, to my knowledge of how C and my app/API works :(

that implementation you showed in the updated answer doesn't need any kind of deallocation, right?

Comment: It will reserve 10 characters per iteration of the loop (generally 10 bytes). When you are done with it you should indeed call free to deallocate it, as I said in the answer.

Comment: got the same issue, I can't do that as the member `title` is constant.

and where/how exactly should I call `free()`? /noob

Comment: managed to get it working declaring a variable inside the loop with malloc, snprintf'ing it, and then using that to create the struct. :D

My only question is about `free()` now. Would it be when the screen is closing? Or the fact I'm destroying the menu would be enough for that memory created with `malloc` to vanish as well?

Comment: The memory is reserved until either the process terminates, or you call free. I'm not sure what you mean by menu or screen but you probably need to free when you're done with it ;)